# How to synchronize message status updates in Delphi Indy

Tags: delphi, imap, indy, indy10

RFC 3501 [states in section 6.1.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.1.2) that you should use the `NOOP` command for polling.

Though in `TIdIMAP4` there's only the [`KeepAlive`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdIMAP4_KeepAlive.html) method using it, which is implemented as a procedure, i.e. doesn't return anything.

So how to check for status updates like e.g. new messages or read status changes? I.e. how can I do manual polling with `TIdIMAP4`? Which methods and properties are involved in doing that? And how to get the (U)IDs these messages?

Or is it even possible to use the `IDLE` command specified in [RFC 2177](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) to avoid polling and to get updates automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMAP is technically an asynchronous protocol, but `TIdIMAP4` is currently implemented as a synchronous client.  As such, unexpected/out-of-order data is either discarded, treated as untagged data, or treated as error data, depending on timing and context.  Untagged/extra data is accessible from the `TIdIMAP4.LastCmdResult` property, which you can type-cast to `TIdReplyIMAP4` to access its `Extra` sub-property.

`IDLE` is not currently supported in `TIdIMAP4`.  There are tickets in Indy's issue trackers (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/indyproject/issues/detail?id=162) and [here](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/19628)) to add `IDLE` support in a future release, maybe in Indy 11.  Until then, you will have to poll the mailbox envelopes periodically, keeping track of messages you have already seen so you can detect new messages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `IDLE` to avoid `NOOP` and in general it's a good idea.

However, that won't give you any results. In a way, IMAP commands don't have results. They tell the server what you want, and the server tells you things. The server is free to tell you things for other reasons as well, including the goodness of its heart.

You might say that `NOOP` means "hi server, now is a good time to tell me things, I'm listening" and `IDLE` means "hi server, I'm listening all the time, so just tell me whatever you want whenever you want". Both also mean "and btw, restart your inactivity timeout if you have one".

The server will send you `EXISTS`, `FETCH` and other responses, which I expect TIdIMAP4 forwards to you in some way. (Yes, they're called responses even though they're not in response to any command of yours. They may be sent in response to someone else having sent you mail, for instance. Stupid naming.)

Comment: It should be stated that `TIdIMAP4` does not yet support `IDLE`, so manual polling of message data is the only option at this time.

Comment: @arnt How `IDLE` and `NOOP` work in general was already clear to me before. Thanks for the clarification anyway, it may help people understand them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My question is _how_ can I do manual polling with `TIdIMAP4`? Which methods and properties are involved in doing that? Obviously using `KeepAlive` is not the right way to go... The [spec says "Since any command can return a status update as untagged data"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.1.2), though I don't know how to access this untagged data after I executed a `TIdIMAP4` method.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for spamming, but could you point me to the enhancement request for supporting `IDLE`?

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to know what a question is really about, when  it has several tags. I suppose I missed on this one, and thought it was mostly imap when it actually was mostly tidimap4. Sorry.

Comment: IMAP is technically asynchronous, but TIdIMAP4 is synchronous, so unexpected/out-of-order data is either discarded, treated as untagged data, or treated as error data. Untagged/extra data is accessible from the LastCmdResult property. You have to poll the mailbox envelopes keeping track of messages you have already seen so you can detect new messages.

Comment: Add IDLE support to TIdIMAP4: http://code.google.com/p/indyproject/issues/detail?id=162 and http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/19628

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the answers. If you put your previous comment into an answer, I can accept it and close this thread.